# How to decide if a DE has a singular point at infinity, and if so, what to do about it.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I'm trying to understand singular points at infinity, so looking at the example

$$x^2(1-x^2)y'' - y = 0$$

I am trying to investigate (a) does it have a singular point at infinity, and (b) if it does or doesn't, what can this tell us about solving the DE?

I understand that I want to substitute $x = 1/\xi$ and look for an expansion of the solution about $\xi = 0$.  I first note that by the chain rule $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the same as $\frac{dy}{d\xi}\frac{d\xi}{dx}$ and $\frac{d\xi}{dx}$ can be determined from

$$\frac{d}{dx} x = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{\xi} \qquad \Rightarrow $$
$$1 = -\xi^{-2}\frac{d\xi}{dx}\qquad \Rightarrow $$ 
$$-\xi^2 = \frac{d\xi}{dx}$$

So we can conclude that

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\xi^2\frac{dy}{d\xi}$$

Also we compute $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ by $\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\xi^2\frac{dy}{d\xi}\right)$ which is

$$-\left(2\xi\frac{d\xi}{dx}\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\xi^2\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{d\xi}\right)=$$
$$-\left(-2\xi^3\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\xi^2\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{d\xi}\right)$$

At this point I'm not certain how to compute $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{d\xi}$ but if I had to guess it'd be

$$\frac{d}{d\xi}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{d\xi}\left(-\xi^2\frac{dy}{d\xi}\right)$$
$$=-\left(2\xi\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\xi^2\frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}\right)$$

Putting all of this together we get that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is

$$-\left(-2\xi^3\frac{dy}{d\xi}-\xi^2\left(2\xi\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\xi^2\frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}\right)\right)=$$
$$4\xi^3\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\xi^4\frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}$$

That answer disagrees with what I've read elsewhere but I'm not sure how they got their answers elsewhere or what I've done wrong.  I'll assume from here that the correct answer is that

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2\xi^3\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\xi^4\frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}$$

With that in hand the given differential equation at the start becomes

$$(1/\xi^2)(1-1/\xi^2)\left( 2\xi^3\frac{dy}{d\xi}+\xi^4\frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}\right) - y = 0$$

and the coefficient of the second-order term is then

$$\frac{\xi^4(1-1/\xi^2)}{\xi^2}$$

and we want to know if this has a pole at $\xi=0$.  It does not, so presumably that makes infinity not a singular point.  Does that mean there is a series expansion of some sort?

What if the point were a regular singular point?  Would that then imply some kind of solution?  If so, how would you obtain it?  Merely by expanding the solution in terms of $\xi$ at $\xi=0$ and then changing out to $\xi = 1/x$ at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to do the transformation is to first set $y = z(x^{-1})$. Then the chain rule gives
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &=-\frac{z'(x^{-1})}{x^2}
 \\ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} &= \frac{z''(x^{-1})}{x^4} + 2\frac{z'(x^{-1})}{x^3}.
\end{align}
Plug these into the original differential equation, then do the substitution $x\rightarrow \xi^{-1}$. In the case of your differential equation, that gives
$$
x^2(1-x^2)\left[\frac{z''(x^{-1})}{x^4} + 2\frac{z'(x^{-1})}{x^3}\right] + z(x^{-1}) = \left(x^{-2}-1\right)z''(x^{-1}) + 2\left(x^{-1} + x\right) z'(x^{-1}) + z(x^{-1}),
$$
and applying the substitution gives
$$
(\xi^2-1)z'' + 2(\xi + \xi^{-1})z' + z = 0.
$$
This has a singular point at $0$, as the coefficient of the first-order term has a singularity there. So we can conclude the original DE has a singular point at infinity.

Comment: Wait, I thought to detect a singularity you look to the second-order term in a second-order DE.  Is that not how you do it when dealing with finite singular points?  If you're expand at a point where the coefficient of the second-order term is not zero, then you just divide throughout by that coefficient and assume a solution of the form $y=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$, no?  It's only when the coefficient is zero at the point of your expansion that we call it a singularity, I thought.

Comment: @Addem Singularities occur when the highest order term has zeroes, or when the lower order terms have poles.

Comment: Ok, I can see that.  So then can you find a series solution "expanded at infinity"?  What would that mean?

Comment: @Addem It's a series of the form $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^{-i}$. It's equivalent to the series for $z$ about 0.